# Bootstrap Col & Td width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootsrap and I am creating a website that I want to be versitile across multiple devices.  I was reading about the width types (xs, sm, md, & lg) and I saw they are able to scale up.  With that said, should I just make everything on the site with a width of xs in hopes it would be the most universally scaleable?  Or is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

With Bootstrap you can actually specify multiple layouts for the different sizes.
If you look at the documentation on the grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) you'll see that you probably want to specify multiple layouts for the different devices.

Unless you want it to look the same on all devices, in which case, don't specify size.